# What is the most common way to fake access a REST service for unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, rest, moq

I'm dependency injecting a repository which calls the REST service so I thought I'd just inject another concrete class which gives the data the MVC app expects.

Is this the recommended approach and should I be doing this through an IoC container?

Secondly, when creating the fake data should I implement this using a mocking framework such as Moq or just hand code the data?

Comment: How about writing a proxy to that rest service then mock the proxy?

Comment: Yeah, there's a number of solutions - I'd like to know the most common way people achieve this if possible.

Comment: I usually implement Gateway pattern to encapsulate REST API invocation. 
When I do unit test, I mock the gateway.